# Storing a JavaScript constructor for later use

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm writing a node.js (0.12) library consisting of 50% Pure JavaScript classes and 50% Pure C++ classes. Certain functions in the C++ classes need to return instances of the JavaScript classes. I figure I need to store the constructors of the JavaScript classes in `Persistent<Function>`s. Assuming I can get the constructors as arguments how can I store them for later `NewInstance()`ing.

JS

```
function MyType()
{
    this.a = 0; 
};

native.store (MyType)
```

C++

```
void Wrapper::store (const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    // Need to store args[0] as MyTypeConstructor for later
}

void Wrapper::use (const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope (isolate);

    auto ctor = Local<Function>::New
        (isolate, MyTypeConstructor);

    ctor->NewInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Just like in the [example](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects) under `MyObject::Init` you can use the `Reset` function to bind a local function to a persistent function.

```
Persistent<Function> MyTypeConstructor;

void Wrapper::store (const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope (isolate);

    auto ctor = Local<Function>::Cast (args[0]);
    MyTypeConstructor.Reset (isolate, ctor);
}
```